# jQuery difference between 'div' and '<div/>' when adding class?

Tags: jquery, html, tags, refer

I was analyzing a plugin but I realize the author uses:

```
$('<div/>').addClass('sample-piece');
```

instead of the following

```
$('div').addClass('sample-piece');
```

what is the meaning of `<div/>`, `<a/>`...... it doesn't seem to be a valid html tag.

I can't seem to find any solution for this as google doesn't allow me from searching operator online.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$('<div/>').addClass('sample-piece');` create a new `div` element and add class `sample-piece` to it. The new created div is not in the dom tree at that time, you may need to append it to some other element.

`$('div').addClass('sample-piece');` add class `sample-piece` to the all the `div` elements in the dom tree.

***summarize:***

`$('<div/>')` creates a new `div` element.

`$('div')` selects all the `div` elements.

Comment: I have tried using '<div/>' but how come it doesn't create div with the class sample-piece? Can you show me a simple example? thanks.

Comment: @VincentChua Try `$('<div/>').addClass('sample-piece').appendTo('body')`