# Difference between $("<div/>") and $("div")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the difference between `$("<div />")`  vs `$("div")` ?

Comment: You question is unclear.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737435/jquery-difference-between-div-and-div-when-adding-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('<div/>')` : This creates a new div element. However this is not added to DOM tree unless you don't append it to any DOM element.

`$('div')` : This selects all the div element present on the page.

So, the code `$('<div/>').addClass('myClass')` will create a new div element and adds `css` class called `myClass`. And 
`$('div').addClass('myClass')` 
will select all the div element present on the page and adds css class `myClass` to them.

Comment: (so `$(div)` selects elements according to what is inside `var div`)

Comment: Unless the var `div` is, itself, a DOM element - in which case it will wrap that DOM element in the jQuery element prototype (as if you had used `$('div')` to select it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer